# Transit direction for inter city is not working on heremap rest api

Tags: maps, here-api, here-maps-rest, heremaps, heremap-navigation

I have been using Public transit v8 rest api ,the transit response works fine for same county in USA, but gives error on planning transit for inter county
Details
URL: [Sample here](https://transit.router.hereapi.com/v8/routes?apiKey=%20origin:38.23406424942518,-85.7560023665428%20destination:39.9611755,-82.99879419999999)

Answer (score 3):

We have reviewed the transit request for following coordinates.
The origin is Louisville, Kentucky (38.23406424942518,-85.7560023665428) and the destination is Columbus, OH (39.9611755,-82.99879419999999).

However, HERE has expanding its coverage and above mentioned coordinated does not comes under HERE coverage report, please check HERE coverage on following link.

Link: https://developers.here.com/documentation/public-transit/dev_guide/coverage.html

Reference URL: GET [https://transit.router.hereapi.com/v8/routes?apiKey={YOUR_API_KEY}&origin=41.79457,12.25473&destination=41.90096,12.50243](https://transit.router.hereapi.com/v8/routes?apiKey=%7BYOUR_API_KEY%7D&origin=41.79457,12.25473&destination=41.90096,12.50243)

Answer (score 2):

There is no transit information between your provided Origin and destination in HERE API.

From your sample URL the origin is Louisville, Kentucky (38.23406424942518,-85.7560023665428) and the destination is Columbus, OH (39.9611755,-82.99879419999999).

From Google Maps I see that the available transit route between this origin and destination is through provider Greyhound lines (https://www.greyhound.com/).

This transit provider is not covered in HERE API.

The transit areas and the providers for that area of the HERE REST v8 transit API are defined here - https://developer.here.com/documentation/public-transit/dev_guide/coverage.html